# Not able to fetch data from parse.com

Tags: android, sql, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I am using the Parse SDK for Android. I am not able to retrieve the data I stored in the cloud. I stored it manually using the Parse dashboard by creating a class called "Average" and creating a few rows. One of the columns is "squarefeet".

I want to retrieve the object whose "squarefeet" equals the value stored in the variable area.

What am I doing wrong? The compiler doesn't execute the done(params..) method. Below is the code.

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Average");
    query.whereEqualTo("squarefeet", area);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (objList.size() > 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < objList.size(); i++) {
                        ParseObject p = objList.get(i);
                        averageConsumption = p
                                .getNumber("average_consumption");
                        efficientConsumption = p
                                .getNumber("efficient_consumption");
                    }
                }

            } else {
                //something went wrong!
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```html
int area=120;
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Average");

        query.whereEqualTo("squarefeet", area);

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: The done(params..) method itself is not being called!

Comment: If its not called click on add unimplemented methods this will automatically add this.

Comment: Tried all that. Still doesn't work. Is it because I'm creating the class "Average" in the dashboard? I have accounts in the app. The class is open to public for read and write though.

Comment: I tried your code as well. There is no error. The problem is that the done method never gets called. I want to retrieve the data.

Comment: What is the return type of `area` variable??

Comment: What is the return type of `squarefeet` on `Parse`

Comment: squarefeet is also String

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79782/discussion-between-sandeep-singh-and-aditya-prabhu).